# Como puedo mostrar la cantidad de ordenes por año que ha realizado cada empleado en Mysql

Tags: mysql

como puedo mostrar la cantidad de ordenes por año que ha realizado cada empleado.

Estoy tratando de ejecutar esta sintaxis pero la misma no me arroja valor y no encuentro donde esta el error:

```
Select YEAR (o.OrderDate) 
Anio, e.FirstName +''+ e.LastName Empleado,
COUNT (o.OrderID) Ordenes
From dbo.Employees e inner join dbo.Orders O on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
Group by YEAR (o.OrderDate), e.FirstName+''+e.LastName
```

Dicha sintaxis la aplico en el entorno SQL y funciona pero la quiero ejecutar en MySql (base datos Northwind) no me lista los valores

No comprendo la diferencia por ello solicito de su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes concatenar con el + en mysql, tienes que usar la función concat así:

```
Select YEAR (o.OrderDate) 
Anio, concat(e.FirstName,' ', e.LastName) Empleado,
COUNT (o.OrderID) Ordenes
From Employees e inner join Orders O on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
Group by YEAR (o.OrderDate), concat(e.FirstName,' ', e.LastName)
```

y sobre como hacer que se vea así:

```
employeeID | lastname | 1996 | 1997 | 1998 
-------------------------------------------
1          | Davolio. | 17   | 57   | 49
```

lo puedes hacer con subconsultas anidadas así:

```
Select e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, 
(select COUNT (o.OrderID) from Orders O 
where e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID and YEAR (o.OrderDate)=1996) as gestion_1996,
(select COUNT (o.OrderID) from Orders O 
where e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID and YEAR (o.OrderDate)=1997) as gestion_1997,
(select COUNT (o.OrderID) from Orders O 
where e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID and YEAR (o.OrderDate)=1998) as gestion_1998
From Employees e
```

Por cada columna de año tienes que añadirle una subconsulta con el año y no puedes ponerle un nombre que comienze con número por que te manda error, por eso le puese gestion_1996

```
(select COUNT (o.OrderID) from Orders O 
where e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID and YEAR (o.OrderDate)=1996) as gestion_1996
```

Comment: Gusto en Saludarte Erika, gracias por tu amable atención, coloque  la sintaxis en MySql y lo ejecute pero me arroja este error Error Code: 1049. Unknown database 'dbo'

Comment: @maikervasquez diculpa, no pongas dbo, lo copie de tu consulta, edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Descuida, super!!! ya lo vi, aprovecho en preguntar como se puede hacer para que los Anios se puedas visualizar de esta forma:                             
 employeeID    lastname    1996    1997    1998                                                     
         1              Davolio.        17       57        49

Comment: @maikervasquez no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: @maikervasquez creo que ya se lo que quieres, eso se hace con subconsultas anidadas.

Comment: Si, la idea es que en ves de traer los Anios en una sola columna los pueda listar en columnas separadas de forma individual

Comment: @maikervasquez ya coloque lo que me pediste, no olvides marcarme la respuesta si resuelve tu problema.

Comment: @erika_chan recuerda que ayudaría mucho a toda la comunidad si explicas por favor tu código de modo que todos los demás sepamos como resolviste la duda expuesta en la pregunta, es decir si nos apoyas explicando por favor tu segunda consulta

Comment: @Aprendiz lo hare, solo que ya se me hizo tarde, puedo editarlo mañana.

Comment: Claro mañana mismo busco tu respuesta y la voto positivo saludos.

Comment: listo @Aprendiz ya edite la respuesta

Comment: @Aprendiz me di cuenta que me acabas de votar negativo otra vez, te falta un punto, hay alguna razón por la que me votas negativo?

Comment: @erika_chan es bastante molesto me acuses de nuevo pareciera tienes mi perfil bajo vigilancia, entonces lo que procede en este caso al menos para mi es abandonar la plataforma, no me gusta se me acuse y menos de algo que no hice asi que punto final hasta luego

Comment: @Aprendiz disculpa si te acuse injustamente, y disculpa si no te caigo bien, solo quiero participar en el sitio tranquilamente, no se por que me votan negativo sin decir en que me equivoco, creo que la que tendra que abandonar la pagina soy yo u.u